# Android studio emulator size

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, emulation, resolution

I am developing an app and I currently use Pixel3 from the android studio. I want to test the responsiveness of my app and i want to change the emulators size without having the aspect ratio constrains. Is there a way to create a new emulator in android studio so that I can change the resolution on the fly without having to create multiple emulators?

Comment: How do you test responsiveness  with an emulator? Usually apps running in an emulator and on a real device are totally different and therefore not comparable.

Comment: I am working on a Flutter app. So I want to test different screen sizes to detect any overflows and sizing errors. So a dynamic change to the emulator size is going to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is something that you are looking for
https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview